# How do I efficiently search for records with conditions on a one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, one-to-many

Say I have the following schema:

```
create table foo (
    foo_id      int not null,
    name        text not null,
    primary key (foo_id)
);

create table bar (
    bar_id      int not null,
    foo_id      int not null,
    index       int not null,
    value       text not null,
    primary key (bar_id),
    foreign key (foo_id) references foo (foo_id)
);
```

So a one-to-many relationship between `foo` and `bar`; `foo` is an ordered container of `bar`.

How do I efficiently search for records from `foo` that contain a certain set of `bar`s? That is, if I have a list of `bar.value`s, what `foo`s have an associated `bar` for each of them?

Note that I need to store information on the order of the `bar`s, but want to ignore the ordering while searching.

The only ways I can think of doing this are:

- programatically constructing a query with `exists` sub-queries for each value I'm interested in
- programatically constructing a query with inner joins on `bar` for each value I'm interested in

For example:

```
select
    f.*
from
    foo f
where
    exists (select 1 from bar b where b.foo_id = f.foo_id and value = 'value 1') and
    exists (select 1 from bar b where b.foo_id = f.foo_id and value = 'value 2') and
    ...
    exists (select 1 from bar b where b.foo_id = f.foo_id and value = 'value n')
```

Constructed dynamically depending on how many values you need to match.

Alternatively:

```
select
    f.*
from
    foo f,
    bar b1,
    bar b2,
    ...
    bar bn
where
    b1.foo_id = f.foo_id and b1.value = 'value 1' and
    b2.foo_id = f.foo_id and b2.value = 'value 2' and
    ...
    bn.foo_id = f.foo_id and bn.value = 'value n'
```

Is there a better way to achieve this in SQL?

Could I use a different schema to make this easier?

Comment: Using what RDBMS?  Sql Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  etc.

Comment: Ideally not tied to any particular RDBMS. But would need to work with sqlite3 as a lowest common denominator.

Comment: Your question would be a bit more clear if you would write an SQL that works, then ask us to suggest alternatives that would run faster.

Comment: @MichaelPotter I've added example SQL now

Comment: I'm still interested in answers to this question, although I no longer care about sqlite3. Currently, I'm using MySQL, but would also be interested in propitiatory features that other RDBMS' have that might help

Answer (score 1):

I think the exists technique is the best. But if you want to do it a different way, maybe this:

```
with x as (
select f.id
   from foo f
   join bar b
     on b.foo_id = f.id
  where b.value in ('value 1', 'value 2', ..., 'value n')
  group by f.id
  having count(distinct b.value)) = n
)
select f.*
   from foo f
   join x.id = f.id
```

You will have to excuse me if I have the syntax wrong.  I did not build a database to test my answer.

I know some people do not like to use CTE, so here is an alternative:

```
 select f.*
   from (
    select f.id
       from foo f
       join bar b
         on b.foo_id = f.id
      where b.value in ('value 1', 'value 2', ..., 'value n')
      group by f.id
      having count(distinct b.value)) = n
    ) x
   join foo f on f.id = x.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something here, this looks like a simple `Join` between the two tables.

> How do I efficiently search for records from foo that contain a certain set of bars? That is, if I have a list of bar.values, what foos have an associated bar for each of them?

You can find the `foo`s that are associated to the `bar` values with the following:

```
Select      Distinct f.foo_id, f.name
From        bar b
Inner Join  foo f On f.foo_id = b.foo_id
Where       b.value In ('your', 'search', 'values')
```

Comment: No, this would give records from foo where there is a bar that matched _any_ of your values. Not records from foo that had a bar for _each_ of your values.